# Swift JSON decoder API ( SwiftyJSON )

Tags: ios, json, swift

In PHP I can create JSON and decode that to work as an Array inside my code. Is something like that in Swift?

I have the following JSON given by my PHP API:

```
{
    "1": {
        "cd_sala": "1",
        "nm_sala": "Treinamento de Teste"
    },
    "2": {
        "cd_sala": "2",
        "nm_sala": "Teste 2"
    }
}
```

Can I use it in Swift just like I do with PHP? Maybe using a "json_decode" function?

I already searched some functions to do that but could not made it work. I tried with JSONDecoder and SwiftyJSON.

====================

EDITED

====================

I made JSON decoder work when i changed my to:

```
[{
    "cd_sala": "1",
    "nm_sala": "Treinamento de Teste"
}, {
    "cd_sala": "2",
    "nm_sala": "Teste 2"
}]
```

The problem is that i would like that incremental keys on it...

Comment: https://roadfiresoftware.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-4/

Comment: Why use `SwiftyJSON`? There's no need. Swift 4 includes `JSONDecoder`. No need for a 3rd party library. Show the code you tried. Clearly explain what issues you had. There are countless tutorials on parsing JSON with Swift.

Comment: The  index of each object is that incremental keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very easy. First define a struct for your dictionary item, like so:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let cd_sala: String
    let nm_sala: String
}
```

Then create an instance for the JSONDecoder:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
```

and use it to decode the data

```
let object = try decoder.decode(Dictionary<Int, Item>.self, from: /* data */)
```

`Dictionary<Int, Item>` refers to the default hashtable (key, value) class, which gives you access to the item like:

```
// outputs "Treinamento de Teste"
print(object[1]!.nm_sala)
```